# How can I find my own deleted answers?

Tags: feature-request, search, deleted-answers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Show all of my question/answers to me even if they are deleted/closed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2645/show-all-of-my-question-answers-to-me-even-if-they-are-deleted-closed)

Every once in a while I get curious about answers I've posted in the past, and I've not found a way to find the ones I've deleted.  If I stumble upon a question whose answer I've deleted I can see it, but there appears to be no way to find those questions/answers.

I'd like to be able to do that.

Comment: I knew this was a duplicate - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2645/show-all-of-my-question-answers-to-me-even-if-they-are-deleted-closed

Comment: Ahhh... there's the duplicate.  I searched for several minutes but never tried the word 'show'.  In fact, type 'show deleted answers' into the search pane, and it won't give you back the duplicate question you listed.  Very annoyed with SO search...

Answer (score 0):

One workaround is favoriting any question where you delete an answer. Not the best solution, but it works to a degree.

Comment: Won't work if your answer was deleted by a mod or the system due to flagging, etc.  I wonder if the deleted posts come out in the data dump?